# PythonTeX (Python + Latex) error of savefig() in PythonteX Gallery file

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, path, latex

I am learning Python, Latex, and found out about existence of wonderfull package of PythonTeX, which allows to add Python code into TeX. There is a gallery file at this site:

https://ctan.org/pkg/pythontex

If you download all package files, there is "gallery" tex source file, which I am compiling for testing. There is also simple plot generation code (short exerpt):

```
You may want to use matplotlib's PGF backend when creating plots.

\begin{pylabblock}
rc('text', usetex=True)
rc('font', family='serif')
rc('font', size=10.0)
rc('legend', fontsize=10.0)
rc('font', weight='normal')
x = linspace(0, 10)
figure(figsize=(4, 2.5))
plot(x, sin(x), label='$\sin(x)$')
xlabel(r'$x\mathrm{-axis}$')
ylabel(r'$y\mathrm{-axis}$')
legend(loc='lower right')
savefig('myplot.pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
\end{pylabblock}
```

while executing this part, specifically last line:

```
savefig('myplot.pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
```

I get this nasty set of errors (sorry for the size):

```
----  Messages for pylab:default:5  ----
  Traceback (most recent call last):
* PythonTeX stderr - error on line 173:
    File "pythontex-files-pythontex_gallery_withiffileexistscondonplot\pylab_default_5.py", line 62, in <module>
      savefig('myplot.pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
    File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 722, in savefig
      res = fig.savefig(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 2180, in savefig
      self.canvas.print_figure(fname, **kwargs)
    File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 2056, in print_figure
      **kwargs)
    File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_pdf.py", line 2503, in print_pdf
      self.figure.draw(renderer)
    File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 38, in draw_wrapper
      return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1709, in draw
      renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)
    File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 135, in _draw_list_compositing_images
      a.draw(renderer)
    File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 38, in draw_wrapper
      return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 2647, in draw
      mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)
    File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 135, in _draw_list_compositing_images
      a.draw(renderer)
    File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 38, in draw_wrapper
      return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1205, in draw
      renderer)
    File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1150, in _get_tick_bboxes
      for tick in ticks if tick.label1.get_visible()],
    File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1150, in <listcomp>
      for tick in ticks if tick.label1.get_visible()],
    File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 890, in get_window_extent
      bbox, info, descent = self._get_layout(self._renderer)
    File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 291, in _get_layout
      ismath="TeX" if self.get_usetex() else False)
    File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\_backend_pdf_ps.py", line 47, in get_text_width_height_descent
      s, fontsize, renderer=self)
    File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py", line 450, in get_text_width_height_descent
      page, = dvi
    File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dviread.py", line 243, in __iter__
      while self._read():
    File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dviread.py", line 301, in _read
      self._dtable[byte](self, byte)
    File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dviread.py", line 161, in wrapper
      return method(self, *[f(self, byte-min) for f in get_args])
    File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dviread.py", line 441, in _fnt_def
      self._fnt_def_real(k, c, s, d, a, l)
    File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dviread.py", line 446, in _fnt_def_real
      tfm = _tfmfile(fontname)
    File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dviread.py", line 1063, in _fontfile
      filename = find_tex_file(texname + suffix)
    File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dviread.py", line 1052, in find_tex_file
      result = cbook._check_and_log_subprocess(cmd, _log, **kwargs)
    File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 2127, in _check_and_log_subprocess
      command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, **kwargs)
    File "C:\python\lib\subprocess.py", line 472, in run
      with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
    File "C:\python\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
      restore_signals, start_new_session)
    File "C:\python\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
      startupinfo)
  FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Systém nemůže nalézt uvedený soubor

--------------------------------------------------
PythonTeX:  pythontex_gallery_withIfFileExistsCondOnPlot - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

Interesting is, that this problem is machine-specific. I have two other (lot older!) machines, which can process this code OK. One is on windows 10, other on windows 7. The issue is on another device also with windows 10.

I have read somewhere that this error is generated by Python being in directories with non-ASCII symbols in its names. Seeing that, I have put python in C:\ root. Also, I have setup PATH variable accordingly (already in installer).

How can this be fixed?

Please, notify me if full (working) MWE is necessary instead of link to CTAN site. If so, I try to minimize to official file to as small amount of code as possible and edit the question.

Thank you for any help,

Regards, Tomas

EDIT: Just while I got comment, found out, that a folder .matplotlib is generated in my windows 10 user directory (containing non-ACII letters in its path). Comparing .matplotlib content among machines I found out, that if the savefig() function is called successfully, there are a lot of files, otherwise, only two.

Now I am sure, that the reason for this is that while using PythonTeX and matplotlib, a .matplotlib directory is created in user home directory, which (in my case) is a faulty path.

Is there a way, how to change the location where is this directory created?

Comment: Maybe it's possible to add a `print(os.getcwd())` to see which exact folder is the target of the saving? Also trying a different folder and filename might point to a solution.

Comment: Now I found out by using "dir" in windows "cmd," that in my user directory (having non-ASCII letters) is generated directory .matplotlib, that contains fontlist and tex.cache. Is there a way, how to change the location, where are those data stored?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I am having trouble printing (even this simple) information in TeX. I have to find a way, how to story result of print function into variable, that i can view from TeX end, or test it (somehow) in python shell.
As far as being newbie, I try to find out how to give more information.

Comment: I checked the traceback more carefully now, and the problem is this: While trying to find the correct font on your system, matplotlib will call [`kpsewhich`](http://texblog.net/hypertext-help/latex-tools/kpsewhich/), which is an executable that should be part of your TeX install to determine which tex font to use. What the error tells you is that this file cannot be found on your system. Maybe it's not part of your TeX install, or it's not in your `PATH` (you can try to call `kpsewhich` in your command line). In my case it's situated inside my miktex folder in `\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Indeed that I found out that kpsewhich binary is missing. It is very interesting, on all of my devices I am using current TeXlive 2019. On one device the kspewhich is among other binaries in PATH, on two it is not. Do you know, how to install this part of kpathsea maually? I am not sucessfull in searching it. Alternatives are: Try to siple copy the binary from functional PC to others (dirty) or completely reinstall TeXlive...

Comment: Sorry for my late response. Also worth noting, that all of my TeXlive installations were dona by uninstalling older TeXlive and fresh installing TeXlive 2019.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Copying the kpsewhich.exe to my PATH was enough to solve my issue. Thank you very much for your help! I dont know how it happened that it wasnt installed... Would you like to create answer from your comment for me to accept or do you want me to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was caused by missing binary file "kpsewhich.exe" in "C:\texlive\2019\bin\win32" folder, which gives matplotlib information about which font to use. Since before mentioned folder was in my PATH, it was sufficient to symply copy file "kpsewhich.exe" from different device (also with TeXlive 2019 on Windows 10) to already mentioned folder.